# Anyway to decompress a zip or tar in google drive without downloading

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, drive

Using Google Takeout usually gives you `zip` or `tar.gz` in Google Drive.

Is there any way, by API or any programming methods, to decompress those files and put them back in Drive without downloading them locally?

Comment: No, you can't!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't decompress a file in Drive, but there are some workarounds for that. Using the API you could easily develop a solution that [downloads the file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive), then decompresses it locally and finally [uploads it again](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/create-file). As an alternative, you could speed up that process by using a [sync folder](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/10838124) that allows you to extract the file locally. Feel free to ask any doubts about those approaches.